# C++: How to correctly actualize a file against power loss?

Tags: c++, linux, fsync

I have a linux embedded environment.

Here I have 2 scenarios:

**A:**

1. Open and write a temporary file.
2. Rename temporary file to the original file.
3. Power loss

**Result:** After reboot, what I have is:

- 0-size original file and there is no temporary file.

**B:**

1. Open and write a temporary file.
2. **FSYNC** temporary file.
3. Rename temporary file to the original file.
4. Power loss

**Result:** After reboot,

- Original content of original file is kept, although not actualized
- 0-size temporary file

As you see, between these 2 scenarios, the only difference is **fsync of temporary file**, and not the original file. In both, I **did not fsync the original file**.

So, **why** the original content of original file is kept in scenario B?

From point of view of original file, the change is, actualizing it by renaming **non-fsynced file vs fsynced file**.

**How** does this keep the original content?

Edit:

This scenario actualizing original file also failed to safely actualize original file:

1. Open and write a temporary file.
2. FSYNC temporary file.
3. Rename temporary file to the original file.
4. Fsync original file's directory
5. Power loss

**Result:**

0-size original file.

So, how should I do that?

Comment: Have you ruled out any other factors? How do you time the power loss? What filesystem do you use?

Comment: filesystem is ubifs. I simply disconnect the power cable.

Comment: Please post some code. Please post an [MCVE]. `I have a linux embedded environment.` What does the word "embedded envrionment" here mean? What environment? What architecture are you working on? `Rename temporary file to the original file.` Do you call `renameat`? `filesystem is ubifs` what are the mount options? Is there anything else mounted on top of it? Do you create the termporary file in the same directory as destination file? Where do you create it? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly, if you want to be immune to a power loss, you use journaling. That means that (broadly speaking) you store what you want to write and where, you write it, and when it as successfully be written, you remove it (at least logically) from the journal. In case of major failure (power loss or other system crash), you read the journal and apply any changes still presend. Many file systems have options to enable it, and on a journaling file system, you can expect a rename to be atomic and immune to a power loss: the file will exist either under its previous or new name.

So the common workflow is:

- rename the old file to a backup name
- write the new file to its definitive name
- close the newfile to ensure it will reside on disk
- remove the backup file (or give it a different name)

In case of power loss (or any other crash condition), on next reboot things are simple:

- if no backup file is present, the file is in a stable state
- if a backup file is present, it contains the last stable state of the file: the file have to be removed if it exists and the backup must be renamed to the normal name